# Convert 256-wrap brainfuck into 257-wrap brainfuck

Tags: code-golf, code-generation, brainfuck

Usually each cell in brainfuck  has 256 states, which is not enough to tell whether input is EOF or a character (usually `\xFF`). To fix it we can add one more state to it, and EOF (256) isn't mistake from a byte.

Since outputting EOF is also not defined, `.` on 256 works as reading, and therefore `,` is removed from the modified version.

Given a program in the 256-wrap brainfuck, provide a 257-wrap brainfuck program with same behavior when an infinite stream is provided as input. Memory needn't remain same though.

Sample:

```
,. => -..
+[+++>+<]>. => +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
,[.,] => -.[.[-]-.]
-[.-] => --[.-]
+[,.[-]+] => +[>-.[-]+]
+[,.[-]+] => +[>-.+]
,+. => -.++[->+>+<<]>->[<]>.
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code (converter) in each language wins.

Comment: Do we need to "simulate wrapping". Or in other words, does `-.` translate to `--.`or `-.`?

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would be possible. I feel like there's going to be some halting-problem stuff, depending on the specifics of how the wrapping works.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms It's definitely possible, just that there isn't any obvious non-annoying way to do this (at least to me)

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms I think the last sample show it possible

Comment: Problem is, if "memory needn't remain same though.", the control flow's going to get all messed up. Is that fine?

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms As long as it **behaves** same

Comment: @l4m2 That...explains nothing. If it's required that the program behaves the same in terms of control flow, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms l4m2 requires that the output program has identical *external observable behaviour*, meaning that if you give the translated program some input, it should give the same output as the input program would, given that string. Also if the input program enters an infinite loop after outputting 5 characters, the translated program should do the same. If the input program halts, so should the translated program. Basically, the program is treated as a black box, and the only thing that matters is IO and weather the program halts.

Comment: @l4m2 Does "when an infinite stream is provided as input" mean that it's valid to transform `+[,.]+[.]` to `+[[-]-..]+[.>-.[-]<]`? The first program reads stdin and writes to stdout until it finds a 0. Then it outputs 1 forever. The second program does the same, except that it also reads from stdin after the first zero has been encounterd.

Comment: @l4m2 Why do examples `+[,.[-]+] => +[,.[-]+]` and `+[,.[-]+] => +[,.+]` contain the comma in the output? I thought this was forbidden.

Comment: @AnttiP it's valid to transform +[,.]+[.] to +[[-]-..]+[.>-.[-]<] I added that rule because wrap-256 brainfuck can't tell EOF

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <strike>87</strike> 86 bytes

```python
lambda s:"".join([3*c,p:="++[->>+<]>[-<]<","[-]-.",p*255,c][ord(c)%31%11%7]for c in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc7BCoMgHIDxu08hQqD5V2gRG1G@iPPQipijVNRLT@9alx2/3@kLR3571z5CLOv4LNu0v5YJp54Q@fHWUd3WM4R@JJxroRQfjNJiMAMBooURkkCob10Hs9E@LnRmVdtUTVPdzeojnrF1OLFi9@BjxulI6MfbxUeSKS/W9QiHaF2m29nRBsqACEVg/QNjhSOBJAIEEnHNOb9WTtASzBc)

Basically the idea is that we only use every third cell to store the memory that the input program uses. The other cells are simply zero. This gives space to implement the addition code. The addition code is as follows:

`++[->>+<]>[-<]<`

Let's see how this works. There are two possibilities, either the cell has value of `255` or it has a lower value.

If the cell has value `255` then, after the first additions the value of the cell is now `0` (since it's mod 257). This means that the next loop won't execute at all. So we skip the first loop and move right. This square is 0, so we won't execute the next loop and we finally move left, back to the starting square, which has now value 0, meaning that we succeeded in doing `255->0`.

If the cell has some other value `x`, the first two additions will make the value of the cell `x+2` which is not zero. This means that the next loop will execute. We decrement this cell (value now is `x+1`) and move twice to the right. We increment that cell (now has value `1`) and move left. The cell we are on right now has also value 0, so the loop stops. We then move right, to find our cell which has value 1. We decrement it to leave it in a clean state and move left. Again, this cell has value 0, so the loop stops. Finally we move left once to get back to where we started, with the cell having value `x+1`

Decrementation is just addition 255 times. `[`, `.` and `]` don't need to be changed. We triplicate `>` and `<` since every third cell stores the "original" program values. Actually, we also triplicate `[` and `]`, but this doesn't have any effect on the execution of the program. For `,` we just zero the cell with `[-]` and then decrement once more to get value 256 and then use the dot.

Comment: Do you assume no nop in source?

Comment: @l4m2 Yes, should they be handled?

Comment: I guess it's fine but if someone cost some more bytes to handle them then this don't win that